# Changing variable from factor to numeric changes the order

Tags: r, nlp

I am working on a text analysis project in R where I'm attempting to identify words that tend to be used more by one group compared to another (based on bayesian probability). I now have a list with words and word loadings (factors). When I convert the word loadings from factor to numeric, the order changes. Why is this and how do I solve it?

[image]

Then running the following code:

`words$top_words <- as.numeric(words$top_words)`

[image]

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `words$top_words` is probably `factor`.  Try `words$top_words <- as.numeric(as.character(words$top_words))`

Comment: Ah, that seems to work... Thank you!

Comment: Can I suggest editing your question, as I don't think your original data type was integer and as such it is potentially confusing to future users.

Comment: When I check the type it shows up as integer. Am I doing something wrong? If so, I will change the question immediately.
 typeof(words$top_words)
[1] "integer"

Comment: you should check for `class(words$top_words)`

Comment: Thank you for this, you are entirely right. The question is now updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`words$top_words` is factor, hence when converted to numeric they are changed to underlying numbers. To safely convert factors to numbers we can do

```
words$top_words <- as.numeric(as.character(words$top_words))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is also to make use of `levels` which would be faster

```
words$top_words <- as.numeric(levels(words$top_words)[words$top_words])
```